# ExtJS success action not being called

Tags: java, ajax, json, extjs, struts2

I am using `struts2` for server-side along with `ExtJS4` for the UI. I have a simple form which I submit to the server. The response always goes to the failure case of the request though I am just returning `ActionSupport.SUCCESS`. I am using the json-plugin for struts to return the response in json-format. How to check what is being returned? Could someone help me in solving the issue?

```
 validateForm: function(button){
            var form=button.up('form').getForm();
            form.url='addData';
            form.submit({
                success: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Submit success');
                },

                failure: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'Error returned from the server');
                }
            });
    }
```

struts.xml

```
<package name="ELM29" extends="struts-default,json-default">
        <action name="addData" class="com.test.elm.action.Data"
            method="processData">
            <result type="json"></result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

action class:
 I have the getter setters for all variables and The action class extends ActionSupport

```
public String processData(){

        System.out.println("Clip: "+getClipName());
        System.out.println("AS val: "+ActionSupport.SUCCESS);
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;

    }
```

Also, I want to display the data in a grid. I have a method that returns a List object. But I am getting an exception

```
Exception occurred during processing request: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String.
```

I am not able to find what is wrong here. Please help me in rectifying the mistakes in this.

Comment: Please check this http://java.dzone.com/articles/ext-js-forms-integration  once.Please try with form.submit once.

Comment: Thanks...Yea, with `form.submit()` the parameters are being passed to Struts but the response goes to the failure case

Comment: Please Try with return Action.SUCCESS once.

Comment: Ok..I am trying that now. I am not sure if the response is being returned or not..How can I check what is being returned?

Comment: Tried with Action.SUCCESS...but still the same problem..

Comment: This is the json plugin in the lib folder: `struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar`

Comment: Did you check the link i provided?Please check once.Add the json-default that is mentioned in that article.It might work.The article is same case as yours.Try once.

Comment: I was able to resolve that issue.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by doing the following things:

-created a boolean variable success
    `private boolean success`

-added the getter and setter method for the variable `success`

-set the value of `success` to `true` in the method..in my case it is `processData()`

By doing this, in the json response there will be an attribute called `success` with the value set to `true`.

Hope it helps someone.!